# Is it necessary to use multiple PSUs?

Tags: power-supply, hp-proliant

I recently bought a used Server (hp proliant dl580 g5) for home use. It has two Power Supply Units.  Is it necessary that I have to power up both in order to use it or can I simply ignore one and use it like a normal Desktop?

Comment: Down voter please can you explain what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dual power supplies in servers are for redundancy. If one fails the other will keep the server powered. Being "hot swappable" allows for replacing the defective unit without powering down the server.

According to the [product overview](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01410463) in the HP Support Center your server is equipped with;

> Rear accessible Hot Plug Redundant Power Supplies (RPS optional on
>   some models)

If you are not concerned about this redundancy, you should be able to run the server on a single power supply.